# Regex to convert JSON into an array of blocks ignoring whitespace in vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, json, regex

There are many posts on converting JSON into arrays in JavaScript, however, the search results I reviewed do not produce the specific desired results I am seeking (described below).

I'm looking for a RegEx that can convert JSON into an array of all characters (commas, curly brackets for objects, brackets for arrays, colons, escape characters, null, etc.) but ignores whitespace.

Psuedo-code for RegEx:

> Match any curly bracket char (open and closed), any word wrapped in
> parenthesis, colon char, comma char, bracket char (open and closed),
> number, and null.

**Sample Input String (JSON will change)**

```
 { 
   "hello":"world",
   "\"foo\"":"bar",
   "my_object":{
     "my_array": [
        1,
        null,
        { "my_key":"my_value" }
     ]
   }
 }
```

**Desired Output From RegEx**

```
[ 
   "{", "hello", ":", "world", ",", "\"foo\"", ":", "bar", ",", "my_object",":", "{", "my_array", ":", "[", 1, ",", null, ",", "{", "my_key", ":", "my_value", "}", "]", "}", "}"
]
```

Thank you!

Comment: @GhostOps could you give an example, I don't know how to use your feedback to generate the RegEx

Comment: sry, wrong suggestion, nvm

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: The JSON you've provided isn't actually JSON; having `"my_key":"my_value"` as a single array element isn't valid per spec. Separately - can you elaborate on why this is necessary to use a RegExp for? Why not just algorithmically reduce the structures to the desired array?

Comment: @esqew - thank you, you are correct, I updated the JSON to be valid (verified with linter), I missed that. Any suggestion on how to algorithmically reduce the structure? Would love to explore that option. Because the JSON input needs to be generalizable to any size, length, structure, etc., I thought RegEx might be the optimal approach. Would love to hear another (possibly easier and more efficient) option. Thanks!

Comment: @RonI I may be able to give it a shot, but at least at first glance this is a textbook use case for a recursive algorithm to digest the components of the structure and output the Array you're looking for.

Comment: @esqew that's exactly correct. I'm working on creating a JSON editor which would allow the user to click on individual 'blocks' of JSON in order to dynamically generate flat relational tables. A generalizable, recursive algorithm that breaks down JSON input into an array (what this post is about) would then let me create a custom parser to add metadata to each JSON 'block' (my greater goal). I thought RegEx would be the way to go, but if there's another way that would be pretty awesome.

Comment: @SamridhTuladhar I will respond with psuedo code because my multiple RegEx attempts have all failed hah! pseudo-code: Match any curly bracket char (open and closed), any word wrapped in parenthesis, colon char, comma char, bracket char (open and closed), number, and null. Any chance you can help me write that as a regex that outputs the matches in an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RegExp is good at quite a number of tasks, but I still strongly recommend *not* using it with data structures like JSON (or, god forbid, XML/HTML).

Since this is literally a data structure in JavaScript, use a recursive function to get the output you want:

```js
const jsdoc = {
  "hello": "world",
  "\"foo\"": "bar",
  "my_object": {
    "my_array": [
      1,
      null,
      {
        "my_key": "my_value"
      }
    ]
  }
}

const parseToArray = obj => {
  var res = [];
  if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
    res.push('[');
    for (entry of obj) {
      var parsed = parseToArray(entry);
      //while (Array.isArray(parsed)) parsed = parseToArray(entry);
      res.push(parsed, ',');
    }
    res.splice(-1);
    res = [...res, ']', ','];
  }
  else if (obj && typeof obj === 'object') {
    obj = Object.entries(obj);
    res.push("{");
    for (entry of obj) {
      res = [...res, entry[0], ":", ...parseToArray(entry[1]), ','];
    }
    res.splice(-1);
    res.push("}");
  } else {
    res = typeof obj === 'string' ? [obj] : obj;
  }
  return Array.isArray(res) ? res.flat() : res;
}

console.log(parseToArray(jsdoc));
```

**NOTE**: The way this script handles comma separators is not JSON-compliant; that is, it may spit back commas where there is no proceeding element in an Array structure. With a bit more work this could probably be resolved.

**ANOTHER NOTE**: This is probably, at best, PoC-level code - **it's very ugly and inefficient**, and there are likely many optimizations that can be made to this. It may go without saying, but this will absolutely not scale that well in production without substantial tweaking. However I think it does demonstrate that it's much less of a headache to flatten your JSON this way, as opposed to trying to account for any and all weird edge cases you might encounter using RegExp.

Comment: Wonderful, thanks for helping out, and I appreciate the comments above. I'll take what you created and tweak it for the above use case you highlighted. I couldn't find a snippet which does this, so hopefully your answer can be of use to others as well.